# VSCode LSP (Language Server Protocol) DidDeleteFiles Notification not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I am building VSCode plugin using VSCode language server. Delete file notification not working.

**Server code:**

```
this.connection.workspace.onDidDeleteFiles(event => this.fileDeleteHandler(event))
```

**Server Dependencies**

```
"vscode-json-languageservice": "4.1.8",
"vscode-languageserver": "^7.0.0",
"vscode-languageserver-textdocument": "^1.0.1",
"vscode-languageserver-types": "^3.16.0",
"vscode-nls": "^5.0.0",
"vscode-uri": "^3.0.2"
```

**Client Dependencies**

```
"fs-extra": "^9.1.0",
"request-light": "^0.5.7",
"vscode-languageclient": "7.0.0",
"vscode-nls": "^3.2.1",
"vscode-uri": "^2.0.3",
"yaml-language-server": "next"
```

Comment: Are you sure that no DeleteFile events are sent and that it's not `fileDeleteHandler` malfunctioning?

Comment: @md2perpe I added a log message in fileDeleteHandler. Event itself is not firing

Comment: Do you have the code in a public repository so that we can test and look around in other places for a possible cause of the error?

Comment: I verified on this repo: https://github.com/redhat-developer/yaml-language-server
Here also delete event not triggering  @md2perpe

Comment: I have the same issue, @venkat7668 were you able to solve it, please?